# What is wrong with this attempt to get a JSON value?

Tags: json, vb.net, reference, label

I'm trying to get the Json value and put it in a label, the syntax seems to be correct, but there sure is something wrong with the code, the value simply doesn't display on the Label. What can it be?

**NOTE:** I have already added the Newstonsoft JSON reference and the timer is 5 seconds and is activated after the form is loaded.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim json = New IO.StreamReader(DirectCast(DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/"), Net.HttpWebRequest).GetResponse, Net.HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
    Dim rq As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json.ReadToEnd)

    BitCoinPrice = $"{rq.SelectToken("last")}"

    Label1.Text = BitCoinPrice

End Sub
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on `there sure is something wrong`?  Error message? Syntax error? Wrong data?  Its vague descriptions like that which lead to downvotes.  Read [ask] for tips and more

Comment: Nothing, the value simply doesn't display on the Label.

Comment: So, its a common ordinary debugging issue...

Comment: I updated the publication giving more details.

Comment: ..and what did you learn from debugging your code?  Is `rq` getting a value?  Or is the issue later with your attempt at parsing? Is there a problem with assigning a decimal or double to a text property?  (There is, put `option Strict On` at the top of your file).  You have the same debugger everyone else has, fire it up

Answer (score 0):

I was inattentive but realized that I put the code to activate the **Timer1** in the wrong place, instead of putting it when the form loads, it was in when **WebBrowser1** loads.

**Wrong**

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

Timer1.Enabled = True 'Wrong Place

End Sub
```

**Correct**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Timer1.Enabled = True 'Correct Place

End Sub
```

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the help.